# A way to get a genuine value from slient-side

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, request, csrf

I have to get value from client to server and exclude the possibility of its substitution because it is very important (value is a timestamp of action). Is it possible to send fake value or there is no reason to worry? How to do it?

Comment: why u don't grenade the date on the server?

Comment: The project is an online game where even 50ms is important. I tried to create timestamp on the client, and GET timestamp from server (on localhost). The difference between two was 12-50ms, but when server was executing scheduled tasks, difference was ~1000ms. I think other factors will increase the number but as I said earlier, even 50ms is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to send fake value

Yes, it is. In online multiplayer games you usually don't allow client to take any part in game logic, except for sending user input to server.

> How to do it?

You can use [getTime()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp) if you still want to.

> The difference between two was 12-50ms, but when server was executing scheduled tasks, difference was ~1000ms.

That's called latency, or the delay between request is sent and request is processed + result returned. You should work on your server performance. I don't actually see, why would generating timestamp on client-side make any better for you in this case - client still will get response from your server after this time passes.

The only thing I can imagine is when user gets their info from another informational channel (not your server, skype probably or smth.). In all other cases why would you bother, when all players get same latency?

P.S.: You should give some context on your question, otherwise people can only guess about your final goal.

Comment: My question is about possibility of sending fake value. As you mentioned, client cannot take any part in game logic. The last thing I would like to clarify:
Can client inject his part of logic? So, I can create a function, for example:
`
    function send() {
        var a = "not_fake";
        //post request with request_body (string a)
    }
`
Can client send post request on the server with request_body "fake" someway? Or it is fully safely and can't be hacked?

Comment: As I mentioned before - any client-side data can be forged by user, in different ways - starting from editing/replacing your js script with own, ending with proxying requests from browser and changing data there. There is no way to be fully protected in this case. Any attempts to protect it "codewise" will just lead to increasing time for a "hacker" to reverse your app and start forging data. To the second q: User can't actually intervent in your server logic, if you appropriately handle data recieved (validate data types, remove specchars before using value in SQL query, etc.).

Comment: Just to clarify: >My question is about possibility of sending fake value. ANSWER IS "Yes, the user is always capable of sending fake value"

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer! I will award you in 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

i will get the current date using the date function in javscript before sending the request to server(will store it) and after reaching the server will generate a new timestamp using,

Timestamp(dateFormat.parse(strDate).getTime()).toString();

now i will know the difference